# Equivalence of quadratic forms if they have the same signature.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, quadratic-forms

While studying for linear algebra, I came across an assignment that I'm having trouble with. I don't know a bit which side to start from. Namely:

We say that two quadratic forms $a: V \to K$, $b: W \to K$ are equivalent if there exists a linear isomorphism $\alpha: V \to W$ so that $a = b \circ \alpha$. Prove that the quadratc forms $a$ and $b$ are equivalent iff they have the same signature.

Could someone give me some guidance or tips? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no information about it, but I think yes.

Comment: What is your definition of signature?

Comment: Let $B, C$ - base of $V$, $Q: V \to \Bbb{R}$ - quadratic form. 
$b_{i} \in B$, $c_{i} \in C$
$Q\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x_{i}b_{i}\right) =  \lambda_{1}x_{1}^2 + ... +\lambda_px_{p} -\mu_{p+1}x_{p+1}+...+\mu_{p+q}x_{p+q}$
$Q\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x_{i}c_{i}\right) =  \eta_{1}x_{1}^2 + ... +\eta_kx_{k} -\xi_{k+1}x_{k+1}+...+\xi_{k+j}x_{k+j}$

$\eta_{i},\xi_{i},\lambda_{i},\mu_{i} >0$
Then $p = k$, $q = j$.

Pair $(p,q)$ is the signature of quadratic form $Q$.

Comment: @artobjective "Signature" does not exist for arbitrary fields, you should specify $K = \mathbb R$ if that's what you mean.

Comment: @ronno Nondegeneracy is irrelevant here. Of course you can distinguish between $x^2-y^2$ and $0$, one is identically zero and the other isn't.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I had in mind the alternate definition $p - q$ of signature. Which is equivalent to $(p, q)$ if you know the dimension of the underlying vector space but not otherwise.

Comment: as symmetric matrices: Given the Hessian matrix $H$ of a quadratic form, one may find, without difficulty, a nonsingular matrix $P$  such that $P^T HP = D$  is diagonal; Sylvester's law of inertia says that the negative, zero, and positive counts of diagonal elements in $D$ are precisely the counts  for the eigenvalues of $H.$  Furthermore, we can then take a diagonal nonsingular  $P_1$ so that all  entries of $P_1^T P^T H P P_1$  are $0,1,-1$ If some $H_3, H_4$   map to the same such diagonal matrix,.......

Comment: meanwhile,   I said "without difficulty"   as it is just repeated completing the square. But, for the squeamish, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 0):

I assume $K = \mathbb R$, otherwise the question doesn't make sense. ($\mathbb C$ also works, but "signature" is slightly different in this case.)

If $a, b$ have the same signature $(p,q,r)$ then by definition there are isomorphisms $\alpha : \mathbb R^n \to V$ and $\beta : \mathbb R^n \to W$ such that
$$
  a\circ\alpha = c = b\circ\beta
$$
where $c : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is the quadratic form
$$
  c(x_1, \dotsc, x_p, y_1, \dotsc, y_p, z_1, \dotsc, z_r) = \sum_{i=1}^p x_i^2 - \sum_{i=0}^q y_i^2.
$$
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are isomorphisms, so what can you conclude from $a\circ\alpha = b\circ\beta$?

---

For the other direction, I think that thinking about bases is a bit clearer. If $a$ has signature $(p,q,r)$ then there is a basis
$$
  u_1, \dotsb, u_p, v_1, \dotsc, v_q, w_1, \dotsc, w_r \in V
$$
such that
$$
  a\left(\sum_{i=1}^px_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^qy_iv_i + \sum_{i=1}^rz_iw_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^px_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^qy_i^2.
$$
Because $a$ and $b$ are equivalent there is a linear isomorphism $\alpha$ such that $a = b\circ\alpha$.

Now apply $\alpha$ to the above basis. What do you get? What does this say about $b$?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are isomorphisms, then we can write $a = b \circ\beta\circ\alpha^{-1}$ and $\beta\circ\alpha^{-1}$ is an isomoprhism?

Comment: @artobjective Yep, that's it.

Comment: And what about the second implication, I mean, if they are equivalent then they have the same signature?

Comment: @artobjective See my edit.